# Query result is memory address

Tags: go

I'm new to go and still confused about pointers but I have followed the instructions for querying multiple rows but the result I get back is series of memory addresses instead of actual values.

This same structure, minus the `rows.Next()` works just fine for a single user so I'm confused as to the origin of the problem here.

Ultimately I'm trying to use the results of the function in a template but I'm trying to figure out the structure of it so I can range it in my HTML.

For example, if I try to run the code below, I get something like: `&{[0xc... 0xc... 0xc...]}`

```
type User struct {
    Id   int    `json:"int"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Role string `json:"role"`
}

type Users struct {
    Users []*User
}

func getUsers(company string) *Users {
    users := Users{}

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT Id, Name, Role...")
    // Check err

    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        user := &User{}

        err = rows.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Name, &user.Role)
        // Check err

        users.Users = append(users.Users, user)
    }

    err = rows.Err()
    // Check err

    return &users
}
```

This is how I'm attempting to use the function

```
func userView(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    res := getUsers("test") // Should return 3 results

    fmt.Println(res.Users)
}
```

Comment: That is just how `fmt` is printing the value. The struct field values should have been correctly assigned.

Comment: @Tim Cooper but if somewhere else i do `res := getUsers("test")` and use `fmt.Println(res.Users)` I thought it would print me every user, ,is there a way to get that expected behavior?

Comment: @Flimzy Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in your fetching of the data, it's in your display of the data.  `fmt.Println()` prints memory addresses when given pointers--so it's behaving exactly as expected.

If you instead do:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", res.Users)
```

you'll get a different result, probably closer to what you expect.

If you're planning to use a template, then you should do so--your template should be able to access the fields of each `User` just fine.

But the short answer is: Your testing method is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Type `Users` is a slice of pointers. If you print the return value of `getUsers` it looks like a bunch of memory addresses. This is OK.

If you want to print something more meaningful, write a `String()` method for `Users` in which you dereference each pointer and build a string containing struct fields.

Comment: My goal is to output the users object to a template so preserving the struct is important.

Comment: HTML template knows how to dereference a pointer, so ranging the slice of `Users` should be fine. Having a custom `String` method can help you to debug though.